# Moveit with Octomap from SLAM package

Tags: slam, navigation, moveit, octomap, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm using the SLAM package rtabmap, this package is able to output an octomap that's automatically updated on loop closures

I want to use moveit to navigate my drone in its environnement (that works) but I don't want moveit to compute another occupancy map since I already have rtabmap to do it and rtabmap's map is more accurate than anything moveit could do.

So here is my question:

How could I feed moveit with an external octomap (and disable the internal octomap computation)?

Thanks a lot.

I made it work!
Here is the corresponding repo: https://github.com/Notou/Moveit-External-Octomap-Updater

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265024/moveit-with-octomap-from-slam-package/) by [Notou](https://answers.ros.org/users/30947/notou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-06-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To make MoveIt stop building its own map just disable the OccupancyMapUpdater that is configured in your moveit config.
To get the rtabmap-octomap into the `move_group` node you will have to write a new `OccupancyMapUpdater` plugin, or re-/ab-use the `pointcloud_octomap_updater` plugin at the cost of possibly big delays.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Notou](https://answers.ros.org/users/30947/notou/) on 2017-07-04**:
Thanks, This seem the proper solution.
I'll mark your answer when I finally manage to have it working :)

edit:

Yep, it works!

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-07-05**:
Do you have the new plugin available online?
This is clearly of interest to others, so I would very much encourage you to put it into some repository online (or contribute it to MoveIt! if you don't wish to maintain it).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-07**:
It's not directly from a topic, but a possible alternative could have been the `moveit_msgs/LoadMap` service that is exposed by the `OccupancyMapMonitor` in MoveIt?

**Comment by [Notou](https://answers.ros.org/users/30947/notou/) on 2017-07-07**:
It's a possibility yes, and it would be easier too.
That being said, I did not really consider it because I don't really like the idea of having to write and read a file that can be quite big more than once a second...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-07**:
I was not aware you wanted to refresh the octomap, I had understood that it was a one-time thing. Using services for a continuous update is not a good idea.

**Comment by [JunTuck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26970/juntuck/) on 2021-10-26**:
Hi, I'm also feeding external Octomaps to MoveIt, but I do so via publishing a PlanningScene message (that contains an Octomap message) to the topics "/move_group/monitored_planning_scene" and "/planning_scene". Is there a (dis)advantage to this method in comparison to OP's custom plugin approach?